# Is it possible (and recommended) to use Javascript to perform server-side scripting?

Tags: javascript, serverside-javascript

Is it possible to use Javascript to query databases to display text, images and other data and, generally to perform server-side scripting? And if so would you recommend using Javascript to do this or is it better to use PHP, Python, ASP etc?

Comment: Have a look at [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you hear about [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)?

Yes, it's possible.

Recommended? -It depends, as always...

Comment: Well, this is definitely interesting. I can't believe I have never heard of this! It looks like Node.js would be overkill for a relatively small project although still definitely worth looking at. Thanks, guys!

Comment: @GoofBall How would it be "overkill" if PHP, Python, ASP aren't?

Comment: If you are developing a service that doesn't need to operate in real-time and which is not data-intensive then wouldn't an older technology like PHP be simpler? I have never experimented, much less heard of node until now so I would also need to look at the documentation and learn how to set up a webserver with it. That is what I meant by overkill.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely possible, see [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). Practical? Depends on your situation entirely.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895641/node-js-projects-tutorials) and Aziz's comment for more links.

Comment: links: http://nodejs.org/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs

Comment: Don't have access to Google right now, so thanks for the links.

Comment: (beat me by 56 seconds!)

Comment: It's a race on SO, as always, isn't it? +1 for you.

Comment: Still, race or not, it's nice to see two independent individuals share the same thoughts.

Comment: Great minds think alike, they say. =]